# Почему не компилируется код для вычисления значения функции?

Tags: c#, математика

Не могу никак решить данную задачу. Вычислить значение функции y=f(x) при произвольных значениях x.

[image: задача]

Вот мой код и он не компилируется:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var x = 5;
            var a = 3.9;
            var b = 4.9;
            var y = 0.0;

            if (x == 5 && a == 3.9)
            {

                y = x + Math.Cos(a * x) / (Math.Pow(x, 2) + 1);

            }
            else if (x == 8 && b == 4.9)
            {
                y = b + Math.Sin(a / x);
            }
            else if (x == 2 && (a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 5 || a == 8))
            {
                y = Math.Exp(x) + Math.Log(x, Math.E);
            }

            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Текст ошибки напишите. И сточку, в которой она возникает.

Comment: Уточните условия вашей задачи, похоже, что они определяют значения функции только в некоторых точках `x`, а не в произвольных.  Например, что значит `x = 2x = 1; 2; 5; 8`?  Или `x = 5a = 3.9`?

Comment: 1. Не могу понять почему не компилируется.
2. Текста ошибки нет, программа компилирует но ничего не выдает. Просто пустой текст
3. Видимо по условиям  там не произвольные точки x, а определенные которые я записал. Это точки которые должны быть. Например сперва x = 2 и после нахождения этой точки, вычисляем следующую точку x = 5 и т. д. и так до 8

Answer (score 1):

Уберите второй static void Main(string[] args) и соответствующие ей скобки и все запустится

Comment: я убрал его, все равно не хочет компилировать

Comment: @tukki, именно ошибку какую-то выдает, или просто ответ не выводится?